# plotly animation in shiny app; my data frame does not get recognized

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to generate an animated plotly graph in my shiny app. I get the error message:

First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.

Why is my df not getting recognised?

The data:

```
dput(LifeExpCH$Age)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 
111)
> dput(LifeExpCH$Die)
c(380, 16, 11, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 13, 
16, 19, 20, 20, 21, 20, 19, 21, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 30, 31, 
35, 37, 41, 44, 48, 52, 57, 63, 70, 76, 84, 94, 104, 115, 129, 
143, 159, 176, 195, 215, 237, 258, 283, 307, 334, 363, 392, 424, 
458, 495, 534, 578, 624, 677, 734, 798, 869, 952, 1044, 1149, 
1271, 1411, 1569, 1750, 1955, 2184, 2440, 2723, 3032, 3363, 3711, 
4064, 4404, 4710, 4952, 5106, 5143, 5041, 4795, 4408, 3908, 3342, 
2753, 2190, 1679, 1243, 888, 612, 406, 259, 158, 93, 51, 27, 
13, 5, 2, 1)

> dput(LifeExpCH_M$Age)
c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110
)
>dput(LifeExpCH_M$Die)
c(413, 16, 13, 11, 11, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 15, 18, 26, 
33, 43, 51, 55, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 48, 49, 49, 51, 52, 55, 57, 
61, 65, 69, 73, 79, 85, 92, 100, 108, 118, 130, 141, 156, 172, 
190, 209, 231, 256, 282, 312, 345, 379, 418, 458, 503, 551, 601, 
656, 715, 776, 842, 911, 985, 1063, 1147, 1237, 1335, 1441, 1557, 
1687, 1828, 1987, 2162, 2352, 2558, 2776, 3005, 3239, 3472, 3698, 
3903, 4079, 4213, 4290, 4298, 4227, 4072, 3831, 3513, 3129, 2702, 
2256, 1820, 1415, 1059, 763, 528, 351, 224, 137, 80, 45, 24, 
13, 6, 3, 1, 1)
```

The code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#With this function I want to generate a df showing deaths per age.

Die <- function(Gender) {
  if(Gender == 0){

    People_D <- LifeExpCH$Die[1:111]
    Age_in_Years <- LifeExpCH$Age[1:111]
    df2 <- data.frame(Age_in_Years, People_D)

  } else {

    People_D <- LifeExpCH_M$Die
    Age_in_Years <- LifeExpCH_M$Age
    df2 <- data.frame(Age_in_Years, People_D)

  }
}


header <- dashboardHeader()



sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(



  selectInput("Gender", "Please select gender:", c("Female" = 0, "Male" = 1))


)

#Here I want to show the animated plotly graph.

body <- dashboardBody(

            box(width = 13, plotlyOutput(outputId = "DI"))

    )
```

UI

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                    header = header,
                    sidebar = sidebar,
                    body = body)
```

SERVER

```
server <- function(input, output){

#Here I am using the function from the top to generate the df.

  DieN <- reactive({
    Die(input$Gender)
  })

#HERE I AM USING THE DF, BUT IT IS NOT WORKING?

  output$DI <- renderPlotly({

    plot_ly(DieN() %>% split(.$Age_in_Years) %>% accumulate(~bind_rows(.x, .y)) %>%
      set_names(0:110) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = "frame") %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~Age_in_Years, y = ~People_D) %>%
      mutate(frame = as.numeric(frame)) %>%
      add_lines(frame = ~frame, showlegend = FALSE))

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error message:

First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.

Comment: Solved, mistake was to call plot_ly twice in my renderplotly. Correct code:

```server <- function(input, output){

  DieN <- reactive({
    Die(input$Gender)
  })

  output$DI <- renderPlotly({

      DieN() %>% split(.$Age_in_Years) %>% accumulate(~bind_rows(.x, .y)) %>%
      set_names(0:110) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = "frame") %>%
      plot_ly(x = ~Age_in_Years, y = ~People_D) %>%
      mutate(frame = as.numeric(frame)) %>%
      add_lines(frame = ~frame, showlegend = FALSE)

    })
}```

Comment: yes, one of the things I mentioned in my answer 10 mins ago...

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

1. you nested two `plot_ly` calls
2. you piped a plotly-object to `mutate`
3. `selectInput` gives back string values not integer (if-condition).

Please check the following:

```
LifeExpCH <- data.frame(Age =
                          c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
                            18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
                            34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
                            50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
                            66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
                            82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
                            98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 
                            111), 
                        Die =
                          c(380, 16, 11, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 13, 
                            16, 19, 20, 20, 21, 20, 19, 21, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 30, 31, 
                            35, 37, 41, 44, 48, 52, 57, 63, 70, 76, 84, 94, 104, 115, 129, 
                            143, 159, 176, 195, 215, 237, 258, 283, 307, 334, 363, 392, 424, 
                            458, 495, 534, 578, 624, 677, 734, 798, 869, 952, 1044, 1149, 
                            1271, 1411, 1569, 1750, 1955, 2184, 2440, 2723, 3032, 3363, 3711, 
                            4064, 4404, 4710, 4952, 5106, 5143, 5041, 4795, 4408, 3908, 3342, 
                            2753, 2190, 1679, 1243, 888, 612, 406, 259, 158, 93, 51, 27, 
                            13, 5, 2, 1))

LifeExpCH_M <- data.frame(Age = 
                            c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
                              18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
                              34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
                              50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 
                              66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 
                              82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
                              98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110
                            ), 
                          Die = 
                            c(413, 16, 13, 11, 11, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 15, 18, 26, 
                              33, 43, 51, 55, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 48, 49, 49, 51, 52, 55, 57, 
                              61, 65, 69, 73, 79, 85, 92, 100, 108, 118, 130, 141, 156, 172, 
                              190, 209, 231, 256, 282, 312, 345, 379, 418, 458, 503, 551, 601, 
                              656, 715, 776, 842, 911, 985, 1063, 1147, 1237, 1335, 1441, 1557, 
                              1687, 1828, 1987, 2162, 2352, 2558, 2776, 3005, 3239, 3472, 3698, 
                              3903, 4079, 4213, 4290, 4298, 4227, 4072, 3831, 3513, 3129, 2702, 
                              2256, 1820, 1415, 1059, 763, 528, 351, 224, 137, 80, 45, 24, 
                              13, 6, 3, 1, 1))

# The code:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# With this function I want to generate a df showing deaths per age.
Die <- function(Gender) {
  if (Gender == "0") {
    People_D <- LifeExpCH$Die[1:111]
    Age_in_Years <- LifeExpCH$Age[1:111]
    df2 <- data.frame(Age_in_Years, People_D)
  } else {
    People_D <- LifeExpCH_M$Die
    Age_in_Years <- LifeExpCH_M$Age
    df2 <- data.frame(Age_in_Years, People_D)
  }
  return(df2)
}

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(selectInput("Gender", "Please select gender:", c("Female" = 0, "Male" = 1)))

# Here I want to show the animated plotly graph.
body <- dashboardBody(box(width = 13, plotlyOutput(outputId = "DI")))

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",
  header = header,
  sidebar = sidebar,
  body = body
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Here I am using the function from the top to generate the df.
  DieN <- reactive({
    Die(input$Gender)
  })

  # HERE I AM USING THE DF, BUT IT IS NOT WORKING?
  output$DI <- renderPlotly({
    # browser()
    DieN() %>% split(.$Age_in_Years) %>% accumulate( ~ bind_rows(.x, .y)) %>%
      set_names(0:110) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = "frame") %>%
      mutate(frame = as.numeric(frame)) %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ Age_in_Years,
        y = ~ People_D,
        frame = ~ frame,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "markers"
      ) %>%
      layout(showlegend = FALSE) %>%
      animation_opts(frame = 100, redraw = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Result]